# Session lost after redirect issue

Tags: event-observer, magento-1, login, redirect, session

I have an observer on the customer login event. I want to redirect the user to the cart page after login.

I have this in my function from my controller:

```
Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect('/checkout/cart/');
Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendResponse();
exit;
```

The fact is that in firefox this code works. In chrome it doesn't. In chrome I always get an empty cart , even if I have products in my cart, just after page refresh I got the items from my cart. What should I change in my code to make this work in chrome too ?   Thank you in advance !.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with removing some '/'

```
Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('checkout/cart'));
Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendResponse();
exit;
```

Comment: If I change /checkout/cart into checkout/cart, so without  the first "/" , I am redirected to customer/account page :|

Comment: @AttilaNaghi, Now check my updated answer

Comment: Still the same on chrome :( . My project is on a subdomain. so my url is like test.servername.io/checkout/cart. I don't know if this is a problem or not ..

Comment: @AttilaNaghi, It may be the browser issue. Check in other system or in some other browsers.